# php date() outputting wrong date

Tags: php, date

I am trying this code:

```
date('d F Y', '2013-09-14 00:00:00')
```

and I am expecting back

> 14 September 2013

Instead, I am getting

> 31 December 1969

Does this make any sense at all?

Comment: Parameter 2 must be timestamp, `strtotime(date_string)` should sort this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to wrap your target date in strtotime() function:

```
date('d F Y', strtotime('2013-09-14 00:00:00'));
```